# Python Barcode Reader/Scanner for iPod Touch 4G

Tags: python, barcode-scanner, ipod-touch

I need to know if you use or recomend any Python based barcode readers which I can install in my iPod Touch 4G. I need to know this because I'm trying to use it's feedback into a Django project of my own.

I've tried to download Zbar from Apple Store, but it finds only the reference to the owner of the app, not the app.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: iOS apps are commonly written in objective C. And Djangois an web-application framework. I don't see how your question makes any sense.

Comment: I know the difference between them and the languages they work on, but I wanted to use the result of the barcode reading to input data into an application I'm developing with Django.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [ZBar](http://zbar.sourceforge.net/iphone/index.html) instructions regarding Apple. Also [found](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~peter-stockholm/barcodesforpython/devel/files) pretty python library for scanning Bar Codes.

Answer (score 0):

I use [Bakodo](http://bako.do/) and am very impressed with it. It can scan regular barcodes and QR codes. Also, it's slick design makes it very easy to use and pleasing to look at. As one of the commenters said, most iOS apps are written in Objective C.

Comment: I couldn't make it work properly either, but it is good to know anyway. I will soon buy an iPhone, because it seems that iPod does not have a camera that can be used to scan barcodes due to a focus issue.